# How to understand "Much the best way" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "The original?" enquired Xenophilius sharply, and when she nodded, he said, "Well then, why don't you read it aloud? **Much the best way** to make sure we all understand."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I take "Much the best way" as *It's nearly the best way*. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: The best way by a considerable margin

Comment: [It is very] much the best way.

Comment: @KateBunting Isn't it like the phrase "much the same"?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here, [very] much means 'almost, but not completely' the same.